# Отсутствие частицы "бы" в СПП условия

Tags: наклонение

> **Я мог упасть в яму**, если бы она не дернула меня за руку.

Не могли бы Вы мне объяснить пожалуйста почему с этом предложении (в главной части) не используется частица "бы"? Если я правильно понимаю, это действие не было реализовано (персонаж не упал в яму). Почему в таком случае нет частицы "бы", если речь о контрафактивном действии?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если примитивно, то просто потому, что здесь частица избыточна. 
"Мог" и без частицы обозначает действие гипотетическое, не реализовавшееся. Так что прибавление частицы "бы" ничего не добавляет к смыслу фразы. 
Вообще семантика "мог" и "мог бы" здесь почти неотличима.

В настоящем времени: Я могу упасть в яму, если она не дернет меня за руку. - абсолютно тот же смысл.

А если смотреть в корень, то "бы" восходит к аористу (одному из) глагола "быть". Быть с модальными глаголами плохо сочетается даже сейчас. "Буду мочь" невозможно, а если и возможно, то в другом несколько смысле. Вообще сочетание частицы "бы"  имеет свои особенности, но объяснять всё это я не берусь, это дебри исторической грамматики.

Тут еще сложность такая, что "мог", "мочь" в русском означает означает и физическую и моральную возможность (ангийскиe can, may, might, to be able). В одних случаях сочетание "мог бы" меняет смысл по сравнению с "мог", в других нет. Вот давайте на более понятном примере.

"Я мог бы прочитать книгу, если бы нашел её в библиотеке." - здесь смысл такой, что даже если бы и нашел, то не обязательно прочитал. Но мог бы это сделать, если бы захотел. Это о желании, разрешении
"Я мог прочитать книгу, если бы нашел её в библиотеке." - это о физической возможности. Означает "не прочитал, потому что не мог найти".
"Я мог бы прочитать книгу, если нашел её в библиотеке." - а это утверждение, Было бы правильно прочитать книгу, если уж я её нашел. Так по-русски обычно не говорят, но в принципе это грамматически возможно.

Эти оттенки смысла не очень понятны иностранцу и, честно говоря, не уверен, что на них надо обращать внимание.
В вашем примере их нет и поэтому лишнее "бы" просто не нужно.

> Вам приходит на голову пример без глагола "мог", в котором тоже
>   выражалась бы контрафактическое деиствие, но где частица "бы" (в
>   главном предложении) опускалась бы...

Да тут нет вопросов. В настоящее время поставьте саму вашу фразу. )))

Вот для простоты. *Вам приходит в голову пример без глагола "мог", в котором тоже выражается контрафактическое действие, но где частица "бы" (в
главном предложении) опускалась бы...*

или просто: *Я изобретаю пример, в котором не было бы частицы "бы".*

А с модальными глаголами вообще проблем нет.
*Я должен был упасть в яму, если бы она не дернула меня за руку.*
*Я хотел упасть в яму, если бы она не дернула меня за руку.*
В последнем случае "бы" вообще совершенно лишне.
Я, правда, не совсем понимаю применимость самого термина "контрфактический" применительно к модальным глаголам... Модальный глагол действия сам по себе не выражает. В этом и вся штука. Поэтому контрфактическим (или фактическим)  тут, строго говоря, должен быть смысловой глагол. Но в сочетании с модальным он тоже не всегда выражает действие.
Короче, я не уверен, что эим предложения (включая ваше исходное) попадают у класс контрфактических. Ведь главная часть не выражает неосуществившегося условия. Я ***действительно мог упасть***.
Это надо отдельно разбираться. Может даже вопрос надо отдельный сделать о контрфактивности в сочетании с модальностью.

(+++)
Долго думал. В общем, не контрфактность это. Обычное действие.
Я намеревался прыгнуть в яму, если бы она не держала меня за руку. 
Это было **реальным намерением** что-то сделать в таком-то случае.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! если я правильно поняла это связано с семантикои глагола "мог". еще один вопрос: Вам приходит на голову пример без глагола "мог", в котором тоже выражалась бы контрафактическое деиствие, но где частица "бы" (в главном предложении) опускалась бы... Понимаете как я имею в виду? : ) или это невозможно с другим глаголом?

Comment: @Anonym В тексте отвечу сейчас.

Comment: большое спасибо! даите мне только один день чтобы перевести ответ : )